# Clone an instance of a class, then clone the clone, then clone the clone...?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a need to clone a class from an instance of another class, having the clone inherit the characteristics of the original class with some new/changed attributes defined, then clone the clone, clone the clone etc.  The code below hopefully shows want I want to achieve.  I've tried variations of several stackoverflow answers regarding cloning classes, but I'm not able to get it to work.  Can anyone help?

This is the (incomplete) code:

```
#include <cstdio>

class BASE {

    private:

        int x = 1;
        int y = 2;
        int z = 3;

    public:

        void id() { printf("BASE\n"); }

        void f1() { printf("BASE f1\n" }
        void f2() { printf("BASE f2\n" }
        void f3() { printf("BASE f3\n" }

        void x() { printf("x = %d\n", x);
        void y() { printf("y = %d\n", y);
        void z() { printf("z = %d\n", z);

        void x(int v) { x = v);
        void y(int v) { y = v);
        void z(int v) { z = v);
}

class A {

    public:

        void id() { printf("A\n"); }

        void f1() { printf("A f1\n" }

        void x() { printf("x = %d\n", x);
        void y() { printf("y = %d\n", y);
        void z() { printf("z = %d\n", z);

        void x(int v) { x = v);
        void y(int v) { y = v);
        void z(int v) { z = v);
}

class B {

    public:

        void id() { printf("B\n"); }

        void f1() { printf("B f1\n" }

        void x() { printf("x = %d\n", x);
        void y() { printf("y = %d\n", y);
        void z() { printf("z = %d\n", z);

        void x(int v) { x = v);
        void y(int v) { y = v);
        void z(int v) { z = v);
}

class C {

    public:

        void id() { printf("C\n"); }

        void f1() { printf("C f1\n" }

        void x() { printf("x = %d\n", x);
        void y() { printf("y = %d\n", y);
        void z() { printf("z = %d\n", z);

        void x(int v) { x = v);
        void y(int v) { y = v);
        void z(int v) { z = v);
}

int main() {

    BASE *ptr = new BASE();

    ptr->id();
    ptr->f1();
    ptr->f2();
    ptr->f3();
    ptr->x();
    ptr->y();
    ptr->z();

    printf("\n\n");

    A *a = base->clone();

    delete ptr;
    A *ptr = a;

    ptr->id();
    ptr->f1();
    ptr->f2();
    ptr->f3();
    ptr->x(7);  // change member x to 7
    ptr->x();
    ptr->y();
    ptr->z();

    printf("\n\n");

    B *b = a->clone();

    delete ptr;
    B *ptr = b;

    ptr->id();
    ptr->f1();
    ptr->f2();
    ptr->f3();
    ptr->x();
    ptr->y(9);  // change member y to 9
    ptr->y();
    ptr->z();

    printf("\n\n");

    C *c = b->clone();

    delete ptr;
    C *ptr = c;

    ptr->id();
    ptr->f1();
    ptr->f2();
    ptr->f3();
    ptr->x();
    ptr->y();
    ptr->z(5);  // change member z to 5
    ptr->z();

}
```

The code is not complete - most notably the "clone()" function is not written.  That's the bit I don't know how to do.

Running the program should produce the output:

```
BASE
BASE f1
BASE f2
BASE f3
x = 1
y = 2
z = 3


A
A f1
BASE f2
BASE f3
x = 7
y = 2
z = 3


B
B f1
BASE f2
BASE f3
x = 7
y = 9
z = 3


C
C f1
BASE f2
BASE f3
x = 7
y = 9
z = 5
```

Can this be achieved?  If so, how?

Comment: I'm not sure what your desired class structure is. Are `A`, `B`, and `C` really not subclasses of `BASE`? What *precisely* do you want to clone, an object or a class.... and what do you want the *precise* effect of that cloning to be?

Comment: You might be interested in [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Virtual_Constructor).

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. You have, among other errors, mismatched braces all over the place.

Comment: What are you allowed to change to achieve "Running the program should produce the output: ..."? The simplest thing would to just `std::cout` each of those lines in turn

Comment: Your `main` is also illegal. You can't re-use the name `ptr` with multiple declarations

Comment: Firstly, your code will not compile (even allowing for the incomplete `clone()` function).    Second, cloning has a specific meaning - producing an object of the same type and value as the original.    You're using cloning to describe cloning an object of type `A` as somehow producing an object (or a pointer to an object) of unrelated type `B`.   That doesn't make sense.

Comment: The code wasn't meant to compile - I typed it off the top of my head just to give an idea of what I wanted to do.  Caleth's answer below is almost exactly what I want.  I can use what he has, and create a pointer that points to first base, then to a, then to b etc. to achieve what I want.  Thanks Caleth.

Comment: You don't need pointers to anything here. The `main` in my answer gives the desired output. C++ has value copying *by default*

Comment: That's true, but I don't want the variable name to change.  I just want to refer to the same variable throughout its evolution - so a pointer that starts out pointing at "base", then points at "a", then "b" etc. as the object changes.  I don't need to, but it makes more sense in the code if I do.  It's a little like the base class being "person", and having a pointer to that person but having the type of person change from "baby", to"child", "adolescent", "adult" etc as the person ages.  The pointer doesn't change name, but the underlying class changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want `A`, `B` and `C` to inherit from `BASE`, and be constructable from one.

```
#include <cstdio>

class BASE {
private:

    int m_x = 1;
    int m_y = 2;
    int m_z = 3;

public:

    virtual void id() { printf("BASE\n"); }

    virtual void f1() { printf("BASE f1\n"); }
    void f2() { printf("BASE f2\n"); } /* virtual ? */ 
    void f3() { printf("BASE f3\n"); } /* virtual ? */ 

    void x() { printf("x = %d\n", m_x); }
    void y() { printf("y = %d\n", m_y); }
    void z() { printf("z = %d\n", m_z); }

    void x(int v) { m_x = v; }
    void y(int v) { m_y = v; }
    void z(int v) { m_z = v; }
};

class A : public BASE {
public:
    A(const BASE & base) : BASE(base) {}
    A& operator = (const BASE & base) { static_cast<BASE&>(*this) = base; return *this; }

    void id() override { printf("A\n"); };
    void f1() override { printf("A f1\n"); };
};

class B : public BASE {
public:
    B(const BASE & base) : BASE(base) {}
    B& operator = (const BASE & base) { static_cast<BASE&>(*this) = base; return *this; }

    void id() override { printf("B\n"); };
    void f1() override { printf("B f1\n"); };
};

class C : public BASE {
public:
    C(const BASE & base) : BASE(base) {}
    C& operator = (const BASE & base) { static_cast<BASE&>(*this) = base; return *this; }
    void id() override { printf("C\n"); };
    void f1() override { printf("C f1\n"); };
};

int main() {

    BASE base;

    base.id();
    base.f1();
    base.f2();
    base.f3();
    base.x();
    base.y();
    base.z();

    printf("\n\n");

    A a = base;

    a.id();
    a.f1();
    a.f2();
    a.f3();
    a.x(7);  // change member x to 7
    a.x();
    a.y();
    a.z();

    printf("\n\n");

    B b = a;

    b.id();
    b.f1();
    b.f2();
    b.f3();
    b.x();
    b.y(9);  // change member y to 9
    b.y();
    b.z();

    printf("\n\n");

    C c = b;

    c.id();
    c.f1();
    c.f2();
    c.f3();
    c.x();
    c.y();
    c.z(5);  // change member z to 5
    c.z();

}
```

You really don't need inheritance here, as there is just a data difference between `BASE`, `A`, `B` and `C`.

Comment: Thanks Caleth - this is almost exactly what I need.